# Wrong Output in postman - ASP.NET LINQ Join

Tags: asp.net, linq, join

I have an issue with this controller action :

```cs
public List<User> Index()
{
    var userList = 
        (from user in _context.Users 
        join photo in _context.Photos on user.Id equals photo.UserId 
        select new User
        { 
            Id = user.Id, 
            Name = user.Name, 
            Photos = user.Photos,
        }).ToList();

    return userList;
}
```

It returns multiple times the same user like so :

[Postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vBSn.png)

These are my models :

```cs
public class User
{ 
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Photo> Photos { get; set; } = new List<Photo>();
}

public class Photo
{ 
    [Key] 
    public int PhotoId { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")] 
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

I tried different syntaxes for the database commands. I am expecting to get each user only once with their respective arrays or List of photos

Comment: Your query is incorrect - it's got nothing to do with Postman. You're finding *every* user/photo combination... and then for each of those combinations, you're creating a new `User` object with *all* the photos of that user. If you just want each user once, just use `_context.Users` without doing anything else...

Comment: But the problem when I use _context.Users.ToList() is that it gives me an empty array of Photos in the returned json

Comment: have you tried to delete `= new List<Photo>();`?

Comment: Yes I have but it doesn't display the content of the Photos list

Comment: I assume this is EF Core? I suspect you need some EF-Core-specific aspect to include the photos. I don't know EF Core, but that's what you should focus on. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/ for a start.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right : According to the documentation you gave me, all I had to do is add .Include(x => x.Photos) to the _context.Users line. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You do not need join, just specify in projection that you need details:

```cs
public List<User> Index()
{
    var userList = 
        (from user in _context.Users 
        select new User
        { 
            Id = user.Id, 
            Name = user.Name, 
            Photos = user.Photos,
        }).ToList();

    return userList;
}
```